# jquery mobile fixed panel not working 1.4.5

Tags: jquery-mobile, panel, fixed

Jquery mobile, The demo for fixed panel: not working. The left panel is scrolling with content.

```
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-fixed/
```

Noticed that the ui-panel-fixed style class is added only when the panel is closed.

```
 <div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="push" 
data-theme="b" id="nav-panel" class="ui-panel ui-panel-position-left
ui-panel-display-push ui-body-b ui-panel-animate ui-panel-open">

<div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="push" 
data-theme="b" id="nav-panel" class="ui-panel ui-panel-position-left
ui-panel-display-push ui-body-b ui-panel-animate ui-panel-closed 
ui-panel-fixed">
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `data-position="fixed"` until now is not working properly, so a simple override will solve the problem.

```
.ui-panel{

    position: fixed !important; 
}
```

Though the post is very old, I'll just leave it here just in case someone is still looking for an answer.